# perl regex to match a string and add a string next to it

Tags: perl

I need to add a string in the middle of some sentences separated by `\n`.
For Example:

```
INPUT          OUTPUT
V2+count    -> V2+came+count
V6+num      -> V6+came+num
V10+hi+town -> V10+came+hi+town
```

and

```
N2+hello    -> N2+went+hello
N7+time     -> N7+went+time
```

The code I wrote so far is

```
if ($new=~/\(came\)\|\(went\)/) {
    my $prev_tag = $`;
    if ($prev_tag5=~ /\(V\d+?\)?\+$/) {
        $new=~ s/\(came\)\|//;
    } else {
        $new=~s/\(went\)\|//;
    }
}
```

Comment: All your regular expressions include literal parenthesis, but the examples you have provided doe not include any parentheses, so they would not match any of your regexpes.

Comment: How should you choose between adding `came` or `went` in one specific case?

Comment: Are the `+` characters in your data **(1)** token delimiters — in fact you are working with a list of strings, or **(2)** whitespaces, you just wanted to emphasize them, or **(3)** literal plus `+` characters in the input/output? I am somewhat confused.

Answer (score 4):

My advise is to keep it simple and not try to handle both cases in parallel. So start by adding 'came' to all the cases matching `/V\d+/`and then add 'went' to all the cases matching `/N\d+/`:

```
$new =~ s/(V\d+\+)/$1came+/;
$new =~ s/(N\d+\+)/$1went+/;
```

Comment: Although it may be less readable, the two substitutions can be performed on one line using the `r` modifier: `$new = $new =~ s/(V\d+\+)/$1came+/r =~ s/(N\d+\+)/$1went+/r;`

Comment: More readable, but still one line: `$new =~ s/(V\d+\+)/$1came+/;$new =~ s/(N\d+\+)/$1went+/;`